# Can some function arguments be passed through decorators?

Tags: python, function, python-decorators

I have a function -

```
def add(a, b):
   return a+b
```

Now I want it to add 100 to the result using a decorator such that -

```
@decorator(100)
def add(a, b):
    return (a+b)

class decorator():
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c

    def __call__(self, f):
        def _wrapped_f(a, b):
            return self.c + f(a, b)
        return _wrapped_f
```

The problem is when I want to keep the extra argument variable and not fixed to 100.

Something like -

```
@decorator(c)
    def add(a, b):
        return (a+b)
```

Can I somehow assign the value of this variable during the function call. (when add function is called)
The reason I want to do this using a decorator is because I don't want to modify my function add.

I cannot afford an extra parameter in function something like -

```
def(a, b, c=0):
    return (a+b+c)
```

Hence, the need of the decorator.

Comment: In other words, you want the decorator to add additional parameters to the function?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And if not through decorators is there some other way to do it without modifying the actual function.

Comment: Well, you could just change your `_wrapped_f` to take (*args, **kwargs)` parameters, and add all those up, but I don't really see how you would define how to process those additional parameters in the general case. Surely, just adding more stuff to add to the result does not always make sense.

Comment: *"I cannot afford an extra parameter in function ..."* I think you need to elaborate on that point. Why can't you use an extra parameter? Understanding this restriction seems key to finding a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. All a decorator does is replace the original function with a wrapped version; that wrapper can take as many parameters as you like.

I'm not sure why you are using a class - this would be clearer as a standard decorator.

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapped(a, b, c):
        return c + func(a, b)
    return wrapped

@decorator
def add(a, b):
    return (a+b)
```

Comment: Thanks. Completely new with decorators. Didn't know its this simple.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you want to do with this decorator, so this might not be exactly what you want, but even then, others might find it useful.

You *can* add another parameter to the function, just by adding more parameters to the `_wrapped` function, or even by passing `*args` and `**kwargs` to that function. But how do you handle those parameters? Surely, just adding those parameters to the result only makes sense for the `add` function.

In the general case, you could use the decorated function itself to process the additional parameters. Then, just have the decorated function `reduce` all the parameters using the original function:

```
from functools import reduce # Python 3
def vararg(f):
    """ change two-arg-function into vararg-function"""
    def _f(*args):
        return reduce(f, args)
    return _f

@vararg
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print(add(1, 2))           # ->  3
print(add(1, 2, 3))        # ->  6
print(add(1, 2, 3, 4))     # -> 10
print(add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))  # -> 15
```